# Rendering animation gets progressively slower

Tags: rendering

Setup: Blender 2.90, Gigabyte RTX 2060, AMD Ryzen5 2400G 24 GB ram

When I'm rendering an animation the render time per frame starts at about 15 seconds.
But the render time progressively gets slower. After a few hours it's two times slower.
There is very little change in the animation so the render time should be the same for each frame.
When I restart Blender and continue rendering the animation the render time gets fast again. So the same frames are now rendering at 15 seconds instead of 30 seconds.

The problem is that there is a delay before the actual rendering starts. During this delay nothing seems to be happening. Blender doesn't show anything in the status line on top of the render screen. This delay progressively gets longer. During this delay I can hear the CPU fan speeding up. Task manager shows a 10% CPU usage increase.
Memory usage is constant at about 30% for both CPU and GPU.

I had the same issue with Blender 2.83